# Getting/returning the newly-inserted or newly-modified document in MongoDb (with java driver)

Tags: java, mongodb

My inserted/updated documents in MongoDb have an auto-updated currentDate, e.g:

```
> db.TEMP.update({"event" : "sold my iPhone"}, { $currentDate: {lastModified: true}} , {upsert: true} )
WriteResult({
"nMatched" : 0,
"nUpserted" : 1,
"nModified" : 0,
"_id" : ObjectId("5a6b3799a187fac295097a64")})
```

It's critical for me to know the value of "lastModified" as soon as I write the object. Since WriteResult returns the newly-inserted object id, I can just fetch the object:

```
> db.TEMP.findOne({"_id" : ObjectId("5a6b3799a187fac295097a64")})
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a6b3799a187fac295097a64"),
"event" : "sold my iPhone",
"lastModified" : ISODate("2018-01-26T14:13:45.031Z")
}
```

But that would mean 2 DB operations (write and read) for each one. Is there a way to have the "WriteResult" contain the lastModified, or just return the newly-inserted/updated object (even the cursor to it)?

Oh, and I'm using a java driver, so I need to be doing this in Java, not in the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `findOneAndUpdate` with below `FindOneAndUpdateOptions` options.

`findOneAndUpdate` by default returns the document before the modification.

Change to below to return whole updated document.

```
FindOneAndUpdateOptions options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions();
options.returnDocument(ReturnDocument.AFTER);
options.upsert(true);


Bson query = Filters.eq("event", "sold my iPhone");
Bson update =  Updates.currentDate("lastModified");
collection.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options);
```

Include projection in `FindOneAndUpdateOptions` to return just lastModified field.

```
options.projection(Projections.include("lastModified "));
```

Comment: Thanks, @Veeram , this looks great, I have a few additional questions. If my documents are trivial, then writing  "Filters.eq("event", "sold my iPhone")" is easy, but if I have a complex, nested document? I tried to just pass the document into the query, but it didn't work for me. Also, inserting new documents this way seems risky: what if we already have a document matching the query? I don't want it updated, I want it inserted. Do these questions make sense? Thanks

Comment: Np. You have complex nested query document ? Can you please provide example ? `Document.parse` can help transforming json into Document. About document insertion there is no risk upsert just does that for you.

Comment: sorry for the excessive handholding, but how would a code inserting the following json with "currentDate" would look like ? {
  "equipmentShipmentAddress": {
    "street_line_1": "12 8th St.",
    "city": "NY",
    "state": "NY"
  },
  "timeslotsSnapshot": [
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "email": "john@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Alex",
      "calendarID": "alex@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
} , @Veeram ? , BTW, needless to say , this object can be given to me by a 3rd party resful API

Comment: sorry it seems like a lot of stuff worked for me, @veeram, I'll add some comments i na bit.

Comment: I added an "update" to the question, indeed, Document.parse worked for me! I'm wondering how to deal with the situation where I basically want to insert a document which is a subset of another document? I don't want an update, I want an insertion... thanks for the help !  @Veeram !

Comment: Np. Not sure I follow. So you always want to insert ? Why not just  use `insertOne` ?

Comment: I just completely re-wrote the question , it bloated up, and sorry for erasing the original one, I needed to provide a lot of code snippets to explain what I need to go and what are my problems.

Comment: You could have just asked the new question. Can you revert to old question (revision 1) and ask a new question please?

Comment: Done, @Veeram , original content reverted, new question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469041/setting-last-modification-timestamp-when-using-insertone-and-findoneandupdate

Answer (score 0):

instead of `updateOne` change it to `findOneAndUpdate` which returns the updated document as well

```
TDocument findOneAndUpdate(Bson filter, Bson update);
```

or

```
TDocument findOneAndUpdate(Bson filter, Bson update, FindOneAndUpdateOptions options);
```

Example

```
    Document updatedDoc = collection.findOneAndUpdate(
            eq("name", "Café Con Leche"),
            combine(set("stars", 1), set("contact.phone", "228-555-9999"), currentDate("lastModified")));
    System.out.println(updatedDoc);
```

Log

```
20:41:44.748 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command - Sending command {findandmodify : BsonString{value='restaurants'}} to database test on connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:21}] to server 127.0.0.1:27017
20:41:44.764 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command - Command execution completed
Document{{_id=5a6b43d741b7d10d1cb3edb5, name=Café Con Leche, contact=Document{{phone=228-555-9999, email=cafeconleche@example.com, location=[-73.92502, 40.8279556]}}, stars=1, categories=[Bakery, Coffee, Pastries], lastModified=Fri Jan 26 20:40:34 IST 2018}}
```