# Setting last modification timestamp when using insertOne and findOneAndUpdate

Tags: java, mongodb

I need all my inserted/updated documents in MongoDb to have an auto-updated [currentDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/)

So let's assume I have the following Json *shipment* object (which I'm getting from a 3rd party restful API) :

```
String jsonString = {"tracking_number": "123", "deliveryAddress": { "street_line_1": "12 8th St.", "city": "NY", "state": "NY" }, "cutomers": [ { "firstName": "John", "email": "john@gmail.com" }, { "firstName": "Alex", "email": "alex@gmail.com" } ] }
```

***Problem #1***, I need to insert the object into the DB and set "currentDate", but insertOne does not work for me:

```
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(mongodb_host, mongodb_port);
    MongoDatabase db = mongo.getDatabase("Test");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("InsertOneExample");
    Document doc = Document.parse(jsonString);
    doc.append("lastModifiedTs", new BSONTimestamp());
    collection.insertOne(doc);
    System.out.println(doc);
```

This one does not populate "lastModifiedTs" as you can see below

```
Document{{tracking_number=123, deliveryAddress=Document{{street_line_1=12 8th St., city=NY, state=NY}}, cutomers=[Document{{firstName=John, email=john@gmail.com}}, Document{{firstName=Alex, email=alex@gmail.com}}], lastModifiedTs=TS time:null inc:0, _id=5a6b88a66cafd010f1f2cffd}}
```

***Problem #2***

If I'm getting an update on my shipment, the tracking number is the same, but all the other fields may change.

The following code crashes:

```
    FindOneAndUpdateOptions options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions();
    options.returnDocument(ReturnDocument.AFTER);
    options.upsert(true);
    Bson update = Updates.combine(Document.parse(jsonString), Updates.currentTimestamp("lastModifiedTs"));
    Document query = new Document("tracking_number", "123");
    Document result = collection.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options);
```

With the exception: "Invalid BSON field name *equipmentShipmentAddress*"

- So it looks like I cannot just to put the entire updated document into the "update"
- If I set update just to Updates.currentTimestamp("lastModifiedTs"), the code will update just the field "lastModifiedTs", but I need it to modify all the fields.
- If I set the query to be the new object, then due to my "upsert" setting, it'll add the new document without replacing the old one.

---

Notes: needless to say, I can perform several operations: (1) insert the object, get the "_id" field, (2) update the "lastModifiedTs" field (3) read the object by "_id" and get the updated "lastModifiedTs" value, but it's three operation where I expect to be able to achieve everything with a single operation

How can I achieve my goal elegantly?

Thanks

Comment: @veeram, here's the new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to Problem #1 - Insert `new Date()` to provide new datetime.

```
Document doc = Document.parse(jsonString);
doc.append("lastModifiedTs", new Date());
collection.insertOne(doc);
```

Solution to Problem #2 -  Use `findOneAndReplace`

```
FindOneAndReplaceOptions options = new FindOneAndReplaceOptions();
options.returnDocument(ReturnDocument.AFTER);
Document replace = Document.parse(jsonString);
replace.append("lastModifiedTs", new Date());
Document query = new Document("tracking_number", "123");
Document result = collection.findOneAndReplace(query, replace, options);
```